# Windows 10 Ubuntu 16.04 Dual boot file permission read only in shared parition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions

I have a dual boot set up with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I created a shared partition that can be accessed from both. My problem occurs when I try to access a file I saved on Ubuntu while I'm on Windows or vice versa.

If I'm on Windows, opening a file I saved while I was on Ubuntu, it's read only and I can save the edited version.

I've tried the common fixes you see online like making sure fast boot is off. This is what the last two lines of my /etc/fstab looks like

```
UUID=D6CE4D79CE4D52C3 /media/DualStorage ntfs-3g auto,user,permissions,rw,exec 0 0
UUID=0C7435547435422E /media/Windows  ntfs  defaults,umask=222  0 0
```

How can I fix this permissions issue?

EDIT: After trying a bunch more random stuff I found online, I'm able to access Windows files on the shared partition while on Ubuntu fine (at least read/write, haven't tried execute). But Ubuntu files are read-only while on Windows though.

EDIT2: Anything I download from Chrome on Windows I can't access on Ubuntu. No read and no write.

Comment: I have seen this as suggested permissions: `nodev,permissions,windows_names,nosuid,noatime,async,big_writes,timeout=2,uid=1000,gid=1000
windows_names,big_writes` or this: `defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names` I use noatime for SSD and relatime for HDD partitions.

Comment: Haven't tried this but it's fixed while accessing from Ubuntu now. Still can't access from Windows though.

Comment: Yep doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

go to windows then open settings

> Power Options>
> System Settings>
> Choose The Power Button Does

Unchecklist

> Turn On Fast Startup(Recommended)

Comment: I already mentioned in the post that I already did this...

Comment: Note that Windows 10 updates will turn that back on. And you may not see Windows updates as they often are in background.

Comment: I already did this.